# Can this be formalized as a conversion rule for CoC?

Tags: type-systems, calculus-of-constructions

Consider the Church encoding of booleans in CoC
$$
Bool := \forall t : * . t \to t \to t \\
T := \lambda t : * . \lambda x : t . \lambda y : t . x \\
F := \lambda t : * . \lambda x: t . \lambda y : t . y \\
$$
and the following terms:
$$
A := (\lambda t : * . \lambda x : t . x \ Bool) \\
B := \lambda b : Bool . b \\
C := \lambda b : Bool . (b \ Bool \ T \ F) \\
D := \lambda b : Bool . \lambda t : * . \lambda x : t . \lambda y : t . (b \ t \ x \ y)
$$
We can see that they essentially refer to the same thing. Additionally, we have
$$
A \to_\beta B \\
D \to_\eta^* B \textit{ or }B \to_\tilde{\eta}^* D \\
$$
But as far as I know we can only relate $C$ to the others in the meta theory. Now, my idea is that we could try to formulate a conversion rule (I'll call it $\tau$ for now, because it concerns the handling of types), which would give $C \to_\tau D$ either directly or by also using $\beta\eta$ steps. The way this can make sense is by noticing that in $C$ we apply $b$ to the $Bool$ type and then two values of that type, whereas in $D$ we destructure the $Bool$ type first, so that $b$ can be applied to the type variable $t$ instead, and the values $T$ and $F$ are replaced by $x$ and $y$, which could be obtained in a more generic way for example as $(T \ t \ x \ y)$ and $(F \ t \ x \ y)$, respectively.

For example this works also for the case of a function $Bool \to Nat$
$$
\lambda b : Bool . (b \ Nat \ 0 \ 1) \to_\tau \lambda b : Bool . \lambda t : * . \lambda s : t \to t . \lambda z : t . (b \ t \ (0 \ t \ s \ z) \ (1 \ t \ s \ z)) \\
\to_\beta^* \lambda b : Bool . \lambda t : * . \lambda s : t \to t . \lambda z : t . (b \ t \ z \ (s z))
$$

Can this be formalized for the general case to obtain a new conversion rule for CoC? Has something like this been done already?

Comment: Lookup systems with "internal parametricity", there you can prove these things internally.

Comment: Thank you. It's a line of research that I had not seen before and it seems indeed relevant for my question, and also very interesting in general.